# Is spot treatment of Drywood Termites (airborne) ineffective?

Tags: termite

Unfortunately, my homeowners association indicates [drywood termites](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/urban/termites/c_cavifrons.htm) in North Florida.  They indicate (source's credibility is iffy at best) that spot treatment would be ineffective and wasteful.  They are against any spot treatment, despite having to wait months for a fumigation appointment.

In what situations is spot treatment ineffective?

Update: drywood species are airborne (somehow that this is important) in contrast to the subterrainian class.  For some reason spot treatment is the go-to treatment for the subterrainian class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been in the building trades for 28 years. Termites are generally always localized in structures. Spot treatment is the regular treatment for this.

You should always inspect the entire home though, after a nest is found. Sometimes, after a swarm, the new termites won't make it to the other side of the building before they make another nest, if your home has the exposed wood for that.

Answer (score 1):

The only real solution is to kill the colony and ring the whole house with slow-acting termiticide, like fipronil. Spot treatment is a start, but only if using long-acting poison and when followed up with a whole-house perimeter treatment, including the area where they got in. Not much help only treating the perimeter if they came in under the bathtub.

Or, you can tear down the building and rebuild it with masonry walls and a metal roof structure and plaster instead of paper-faced drywall, and then termites become your friends, turning dead wood on the property into healthy soil you can grow your food in. What a colossal shame that we make buildings out of termite food in parts of the country with aggressive and omnipresent termites.